# Circle-Circle Intersection in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to do a circle in HTML and a part of another circle that is located on this circle. Here is an example:
[image]

I need to do green and yellow areas. Without red area. Tell me please how should I do that. I could do green area with border-radius property and yellow area with clip-path property or there is a better way?

Comment: Don't do this, just give me a hint how to do that

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taz5evbb/) ?

Comment: Hint: "just use `flex`" ;) *Joking* We have no idea what you may have already tried but I would try nesting the yellow element inside of the green element, then give them both `border-radius: 100%` and set `overflow: hidden` on the green containing parent element to hide the overflow of the nested yellow element. You can adjust the offset of the yellow nested element with `left` values, you need to declare `position` `relative` or `absolute` on the element in question for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand you want something like this.
[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2o2Lx6y/)

```
<div class="circle circle-green">
   <div class="circle circle-red"></div>
 </div>

.circle{
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.circle-green{
  background:green;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.circle-red{
  background:red;
  right:-60%;  
  position:absolute;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for